# jQuery setTimeout: 1st action on the row doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

In my small program 
https://jsfiddle.net/Skaidrius/99a48obf/6/
you can push button to show some sequence of moves (color squares change color to white and back) prewriten in array 'seq'. This was made with function.

```
setTimeout(fn(){}, time)
```

Console.log shows that everything is ok, but unfortunately color changes starts from 2 move.

I think I should change some timeout settings, but I tried to correct it without success.

Comment: When you do `i * 500`, i is 0 the first time, so it will have no timeout

Comment: You are right, thank you.

Comment: I removed your second jsfiddle link because you should include the problematic code in the post itself (like RRK did in his answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `i+1` in the `setTimeout()` because in `each()` first index starts at 0.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function series() {
    seq = [1, 2, 3, 1];
    $.each(seq, function(i) {
      var $seq = $('#div' + seq[i]);
      setTimeout(function() { 
        $seq.toggleClass('white');
      }, (i + 1) * 500);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $seq.toggleClass('white');
      }, (i + 1) * 700);
    })
  }
  $('#btn').on('click', series);
})
```

```css
.div {
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  float: left;
}

.div span {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  left: 45px;
  color: white;
}

.main {
  width: 230px;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main'>
  <div class="div" id="div1">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="div" id="div2">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="div" id="div3">
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="div" id="div4">
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="btn">
  Press to wave!!!
</button>
```

Comment: @Skaidrius Yes, it happens. :)

Answer (score 0):

The sequence in your code is "seq = [1, 2, 3, 1];" but if you wanted to start from the 1st item in your array wouldn't it be "seq = [0, 1, 2, 1];"? Since the the items in your array are 0 indexed so the 1st would be 0.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but it will be part of big program, so without seq[0] === 0 will be less mess. Thank you anyway